# On closing questions that Google can answer immediately

Tags: discussion

There are some questions on the site that can be answered with a few seconds spent with a search engine such as Google or Duck Duck Go. There is no obvious way to close them that I can see. Here is an example: [Digital object identification in arxiv](https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/182656/75368)

A comment "Use Google" is sufficient, but leaves the question unanswered. An answer "Use Google" is probably more suitable as a comment.

Should "Use Google" be a site-specific option for voting to close such questions. The boilerplate comment for the close could say "Use Google" or similar.

Comment: I think you have misinterpreted the question.  Christian gave the answer I think the asker wanted.

Answer (score 9):

There has been some tension on this across SE. One view is that as a repository of questions and answers, the entire *point* of SE is to be the most useful/top Google result for whatever question you would ask. Even if you can get the answer on Google easily, if it isn't on SE yet *it should be* because this format is thought to be the best way to get people to the information they need from the question they have. Certainly for many programming questions SO serves that role well; other SE sites fall at different points.

Another view is that askers should put enough effort in their question such that if it's easily answerable from some simpler references they haven't really put in that effort. This has been a big issue on the other sites I moderate, Biology and Psych&Neuroscience, in part because those sites are also trying to avoid being "homework cheat" sites and give students answers that they can write on their assignments directly when they should be learning how to find the answers independently (paradoxically, it's not as big of a problem if the way they find an answer is through an *existing* Q&A post). I think that specific issue isn't as important with the sorts of questions posted here, of course.

I don't think there's a need for a "let me google that for you" close reason. I'd recommend using the "needs details/clarity" option when an asker has not sufficiently supported the basis of their question, for example by explaining why a dictionary definition wasn't sufficient for them to understand in a particular context. I'd recommend using the "depends on individual factors" close reason when the answer is some form of "look it up on that institution's website" (or use a broader search engine to find it directly).

Answer (score 2):

The downvote button is labeled "Does not show any research effort."  Use it for questions that can be googled easily.